# "It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly" or "Can't import 'scikit-learn' though I installed it"

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip

I'm trying to use `import sklearn` and

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

However I either get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'` or `It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.`

I already tried installing scikit-learn the normal way as well as use a past-version  `sudo pip install -U scikit-image==0.17.2`  since that solves it for a lot of cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in another post:

There is no actual issue with installing, the order of imports just needs to be changed. In my case, I had to make sklearn the first import. Further reading [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14884)

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case that the module is installed for the wrong version of python, if you are using python3, use :

```
python3 -m pip install scikit-learn
```

or, for python 2

```
python -m pip install scikit-learn
```

using `which python` will show you which version of python, it is pointing to.

Comment: I'm using python3 for my project and when using `python3 -m pip install scikit-learn
` it shows all requirements are already satisfied. Using  `python3 -m pip show scikit-learn` also succesfully shows the installed version of scikit-learn

Comment: @Zerox Try with the `--force-reinstall` flag.