# How to run Python libraries PIL and pillow in the Unreal Editor

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I am currently attempting to run a Python file inside of the Unreal Editor's scripting environment that imports and uses the pillow (PIL fork) library's Image module:

```
from PIL import Image
```

However in the Unreal Editor's log I am getting the below error message when I try to run this script:

```
LogPython: Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

I already have pillow installed on my computer, however the Unreal Editor doesn't seem to have it installed in it's internal Python package.

Is there any way I can execute or install pillow into the Unreal Editor?

Answer (score 1):

I would be curious to see others approaches but I've found that adding Pythons site-packages path to the PYTHONPATH at Unreal Startup to be the ideal approach.

In the Unreal Python Settings (Edit > Project Settings > Search Python) you have the option to add a script that executes at start up. It's here we append any paths needed in our Pipeline.

```
import sys

if __name == '__main__':
   sys.path.append("C:\\python37\\Lib\\site-packages")
```

Assuming you have PIL, or PySide2 or any other library pip installed then it should become available.

Comment: This seems to work for some packages, but scikit-image it gives me an error of "It seems that scikit-image has not been built correctly", even though it works fine outside of UE.

Comment: @TorbenNordtorp We don't use scikit-image but I set it up to quickly test and it seems to work fine in Unreal for me (just a simple import). I'm not sure what other steps you've taken but are you sure you're not running into something like the below? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67700462/it-seems-that-scikit-learn-has-not-been-built-correctly-or-cant-import-scik